# Issues Regarding the Resizing of HTML Elements

Tags: css, resize, window, html

I've asked this before, and gotten a valid, working answer. Though it seems that my current issue is not affected by the results supplied here:

[My Webpage Won't Retain it's Width When Narrowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20231086/my-webpage-wont-retain-its-width-when-narrowed)

From the answers I received here, the banner I had at the top of my (and others') screen(s) retained the 100% size from the maximized window in the half-sized window.

In Layman's Terms, the banner stayed the same size in different windows.

Now I'm having a more confusing issue...
The other elements on the page (specifically the div's) won't retain that same feature, even though they're included in the wrapper div that I was introduced to in the link.

Instead of spamming your page with the source code, I've decided to just include a link to the .zip that includes my .HTML and .CSS, as well as the images - in order to give the most accurate visualization of what I'm experiencing.

Source Code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/41p4uqu5qowotgk/CSwebpage.zip

Thanks for the help!

Comment: First, if the answer to your last question was correct, you should mark it as correct so the person who answered it gets some recognition.  Second, you need to create a 'jsfiddle' or 'JSBin' example that shows the isolated problem, rather than requesting us to download a zip file and work on that code locally.  If it's the same code as the other question, you already have it written, right?

Comment: Will do! I'll have another comment with a link soon!

Comment: This should be the link to the JSfiddle that represents what I'm getting:

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/QkhBH/1/)

I had to upload and link the images I was using since it's no longer local.

Comment: Not sure I quite get the problem.  What 'feature' do you want the other divs to retain.  As it stands, your `#slideshowBox` has a set width, so that will also remain. The other two have percentage widths, so they will scale.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I kinda did a hacky sort of method but what I did to fix the problem is to create
a div inside your #wrapper div, ided #hacker. I then put your min-width of 900px on that div, and it worked fine. But it threw your absolutely positioned #quotebox into limbo at the bottem of the page. So to partially fix it replaced its rules with:

## qouteBox{

```
width: 48.6%;
float: right;
border: 1px dashed #7FFF00;
height: 35px;
position: relative;
top: -30px;
right: 8px;
```

}

That will get it close enough for you to be able to fine tune it.

Let me know if this helps!

EDIT #1: Sorry I forgot to tell you to add the !mportant rule after the 900px min-width setting:

hacker {quotebox: min-width:900px !important}

This will override all other general and specific css rules.

Comment: I'm still getting an error. To further explain my error, when I have the webpage open on fullscreen - it works fine.
But if you have Windows 7+ or BetterSnapTool for Mac, you'll notice that if you move the window to one side of the screen to resize it to 50% of the monitor width, the entire webpage becomes malformed. If you want the most correct recreation of what I'm getting, the link to the .zip I have on Dropbox is still in my original post. The JSfiddle I posted in the comments beneath the original post also gives a pretty close example to what I'm getting.

Comment: I left out part of my solution... check the edit and see if that works.